# How can I get the localized name of an NSScreen on macOS older than 10.15?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

macOS 10.15+ provides [`NSScreen.localizedName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3228043-localizedname), which provides a user-facing name for the screen, such as "Built-in Retina Display" or "Встроенный дисплей Retina" (if local language is Russian).

However, I need to support macOS older than 10.15, and it's not clear what the fallback should be.

[I see this question, "How to Get the Display Name with the Display ID in Mac OS X?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236498/how-to-get-the-display-name-with-the-display-id-in-mac-os-x). However, all answers use [`CGDisplayIOServicePort`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1543516-cgdisplayioserviceport), which is unavailable in macOS >10.9.

[I also see this question, "CGDisplayIOServicePort is deprecated in OS X >= 10.9, how to replace?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025868/cgdisplayioserviceport-is-deprecated-in-os-x-10-9-how-to-replace). However, all answers depend on [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw), an enormous library that I clearly don't want to include just to get the display name.

(EDIT) [I also found this shim, "get display name from NSScreen"](https://gist.github.com/suzp1984/f14cfab6871e51bee70979a40c1c9760), but it doesn't work properly - for instance, my "Built-in Retina Display" gets the odd name "Color LCD", and it doesn't find a `io_service_t` for my Sidecar iPad screen.

Answer (score 0):

The screen's actual name is "Color LCD", but the user-friendly localizedName (and the one System Prefs shows in older OS versions) has an extra check to detect that it's a laptop's internal display.